# Prove or disprove ‎$‎\zeta‎(-r, x) - ‎\zeta‎(-r) + ‎\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1} \geq ‎\frac{1}{r+1}‎$ ‎for ‎$‎x\geq 1‎$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, special-functions

Let ‎‎$‎r<-1‎$ ‎be a‎ ‎fixed ‎real ‎number ‎and ‎define ‎the ‎function‎ $f:[1‎, +‎\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by ‎$‎f(x) = -x^r‎$‎. ‎I‎n this case, $‎f‎$ ‎is ‎concave ‎and ‎increasing‎ ‎on ‎‎$‎[1, +\infty)‎$‎‎‎‎‎. Also, we know ‎‎$‎‎\zeta‎(r) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty ‎\frac{1}{k^r}‎$ ‎for ‎‎$‎r\in ‎\mathbb{C}‎‎$ ‎and‎ ‏‎$‎‎‎‎\zeta‎(r, q) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty ‎\frac{1}{(q+k)^r}‎‎$‎‏ ‎for ‎each ‎fix ‎complex ‎‎$‎q‎$ ‎with ‎‎$‎Re(q)>0‎$‎. Now, my question is:‎‎

‎‏‎Are the following inequality established‏?‎‎‎

Case 1.
‎\begin{align*}‎
 ‎‎‎‎‎‎\zeta‎(-r, x) - ‎\zeta‎(-r) + ‎\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1} \geq ‎\frac{1}{r+1}‎,‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎
 ‎\end{align*}‎
 ‎for ‎$‎x\geq 1‎$‎.‎‎‎

Case ‎2.‎
‎\begin{align*}‎‎
‎\zeta‎(-r, x+1) - ‎\zeta‎(-r)\geq ‎\frac{-1-x^r}{2} -‎ ‎\int_{1}^x ‎t^r ‎dt,‎
‎\end{align*}‎‎
‎for ‎$‎x\geq 1‎$‎.

Comment: Sure, those things come from trivial manipulations

Comment: reuns. I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: reuns. Since ‎$ ‎\frac{1}{r+1} - ‎‎\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}‎\leq ‎0‎$‎, ‎thus‎ It is enough‏ ‎to ‎show‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎\zeta‎(-r, x) - ‎\zeta‎(-r)> 0‎$‎. Since ‎$‎x+n> n‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎increasing‎, so ‎$‎f(x+n)>f(n)‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎\sum_{n=1}^n ‎f(x+n) >‎ ‎‎‎\sum_{n=1}^n f(n)‎$‎. So, we conclud‏e ‎that‎ $‎\zeta‎(-r, x) - ‎\zeta‎(-r)> 0‎$.‏ ‎I‎s it right?